# How to calculate position of nested element to it parent element on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have set up an example where i want to calculate position of nested element to it parent element.

For example http://jsfiddle.net/45cJZ/ in this example on click event i need to calculate position of nested div element to it parent element i.e `.wrapper` class.

can this be done using `.offsetParent()`

Comment: What have you tried, have you read the documentation for `offsetParent` ? http://api.jquery.com/offsetparent/

Comment: I am trying now, & expiring the same link. I will be more than happy to do it myself.

Answer (score 1):

Add `position:relative` to the `.wrapper` (to make it the parent for the position calculations) and use [`.position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/) to get the position of the clicked element relative to the `.wrapper`

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="div1"></div>
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
    /*...*/
    position: relative;
}
```

Javascript

```
$(".wrapper").children().on("click", function() {
    console.log($(this).position());
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8d62J/

Comment: Thanks you, I was playing around this example.. to see how to use `position()` http://jsfiddle.net/wjbuys/QrrpB/

Answer (score 1):

@Andreas' answer is the best and correct but since you mentioned `offset` you can see how that works like this.

```
$('.wrapper div').on('click', function (event) {
    var myOffset = $(this).offset();
    var myParentOffset = $(this).parent().offset();

    console.log(myOffset, myParentOffset);
    var topDiff = myOffset.top - myParentOffset.top;
    var leftDiff = myOffset.left - myParentOffset.left;
    console.log(topDiff, leftDiff);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/45cJZ/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery [.position()](http://api.jquery.com/position/) to get the coordinates of element relative to its parent. Here is your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/45cJZ/) edited to show the functionality of .position(). Just change the class to see the alerts change. All you have to do is:

```
var p = $(".div2").position();
alert("Left: " + p.left);
alert("Top: " + p.top);
```